# Sun Syndication API throwing error while trying to parse specific RSS feed

Tags: java, xmlreader, rome, syndication-feed

Using the SUN syndication API ROME, 
I am trying to parse the following RSS feed:

```
http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world;_ylt=AmPejPeRK0mzDzsOSrANm125scB_;_ylu=X3oDMTFqbTQ3ajl2BG1pdANSU1MgU2l0ZUluZGV4IFdvcmxkBHBvcwM0BHNlYwNNZWRpYVJTU0VkaXRvcmlhbA--;_ylg=X3oDMTFrM25vcXFyBGludGwDdXMEbGFuZwNlbi11cwRwc3RhaWQDBHBzdGNhdAMEcHQDc2VjdGlvbnMEdGVzdAM-;_ylv=3
```

following is the code for this:

```
import java.net.URL;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url;
        XmlReader reader = null;
        SyndFeed feed;
        try {
            url = new URL(    "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world;_ylt=AmPejPeRK0mzDzsOSrANm125scB_;_ylu=X3oDMTFqbTQ3ajl2BG1p  dANSU1MgU2l0ZUluZGV4IFdvcmxkBHBvcwM0BHNlYwNNZWRpYVJTU0VkaXRvcmlhbA--    ;_ylg=X3oDMTFrM25vcXFyBGludGwDdXMEbGFuZwNlbi11cwRwc3RhaWQDBHBzdGNhdAMEcHQDc2VjdGlvbnMEdGVzdA  M-;_ylv=3");
            reader = new XmlReader(url);
            feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

I am getting the below Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost/world/?format=rss
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:237)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:213)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

This occurs on a response of 404 as i could infer in the HTTPUrlConnection class, is there any workaround for this kind of problem?

This issue is only with this particular URL, does anyone has any idea on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I am not sure but i believe this has something to do with the colon in the feed URL.

Comment: What happens when you access the same URL using a browser ?

Comment: @santosh it is accessible through the URL